# Support to SQL Server 2000 from Visual Studio 2013(SQL Server 2012)?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2000, visual-studio-2012

I can't access to a database created by SQL Server 2000 from Visual Studio 2013, I asked this before in StackOverflow, but I don't get an useful answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21065565/when-i-create-a-connection-to-the-datasource-of-an-old-application-throw-me-an

```
(SELECT @@VERSION = Microsoft SQL Server  2000 - 8.00.760 (Intel X86) 
Dec 17 2002 14:22:05 
Copyright (c) 1988-2003 Microsoft Corporation
Enterprise Edition on Windows NT 5.2 (Build 3790: Service Pack 2)
)
```

After a search in google I found some workarounds with a similar problem:
http://n8v.enteuxis.org/2009/12/getting-microsoft-visual-studio-2005-to-talk-to-microsoft-sql-server-2008/
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/954961/en-us

But two solutions send me to download Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 Service Pack 1 Update for Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Support.

I can't install that, because I don't have Visual Studio 2005 and I need "VS2013 - Olds (2000)".

I have installed SQL Server 2008 (which I don't use today) and **SQL Server 2012**.
[image: All SQL Server Installed]

Don't exist a 'Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Update for Microsoft SQL Server Olds'. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are these backup files from SQL Server 2000?  If so, you really should try to get these converted to SQL Server 2008/2012 formats.  A [blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20151119111228/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/ai/archive/2012/08/09/migrating-sql-server-2000-user-databases-to-sql-server-2012.aspx) from Ahmed Ibrahim walks through a set of scripts that you can run in SQL Server 2008 or 2012 that will allow you to restore these backups into 2008/2012 and convert them.  This will allow you to access easily from VS2012/2013.